# Build Task Failed Unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, msbuild-task

I have error in my project

that is

```
The "ResolveComReference" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0'
```

Can anyone help me regards this. I got stucked

I am using VS2012 and microsoft office 2007

Comment: What do you mean `microsoft 2007`? Do you mean `Microsoft Office 2007`?

Comment: @cybermonkey yes i update my question, can you help me to install package or assembly refrence for this 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0'

Comment: I *think* I know the answer to this, but first I need to ask whether Visual Studio 2012 is the *only* version if VS you have installed?

Comment: Writing up my answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66774/discussion-between-caffeine-addicted-and-cybermonkey).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66776/discussion-between-caffeine-addicted-and-cybermonkey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem usually occurs as a result of a multi-program corruption involving Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, other Visual Studio versions, and Microsoft Web Tools for Visual Studio 2012.

Reinstalling Visual Studio is known to fix it, but however many victims of this issue have said that this doesn't fix the issue.

Instead copying the files from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web`

over to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web`

seems to fix the problem in the majority of similar cases.

Other possible fixes:

- Uninstall `Web Tools 2013` and reinstall the [Web Tools and Web Tools Extensions from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)

Comment: can you please elloborate it more little 

Instead copying the files from

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web

over to

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web

seems to fix the problem in the majority of cases.

Comment: @Caffeineaddicted I meant that it usually works to fix similar cases.

Comment: @Caffeineaddicted If you have more than one version of Visual Studio installed the Web Tools installer seems to be confused as to whether it's installing for VS2012, VS2013, or some other version of Visual Studio and ends up placing some files in the wrong locations.